# Disable autocomplete of Textfields

Tags: php, html

Is there is any other way to disable the autocomplete other than via providing `autocomplete="false"` in html code.In my case that won't works

Comment: Explain why that won't work in your case, because that's *how* you do it.

Comment: please show your   tried  code @Xavier Issac

Comment: ON which browser? Did you check it on any other browser? and what it has to do with PHP?

Comment: I tried both in Google Chrome and Mozilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible values for autocomplete attribute are 'on' and 'off', so just try:

```
autocomplete="off"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Answer (score 0):

By JQuery you can  do this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("form").attr('autocomplete', 'off');
});
```

Please try this .. You can refer [here](https://www.formget.com/disable-auto-complete-in-form-fields-jquery/)